# Select function on procfs file

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking for solution for this kind of problem. I want to monitor changes on a procfs file with `select` (I want to use `select`, not `i_notify`, because I watch another descriptor for a socket).

I've tried with something like this:

```
fd1 = open("/proc/my_file", O_RDONLY, 0);
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(fd1, &rfds);

tv.tv_sec = 500;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
retval = select(fd1+1,  &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

This is wrong, because file is always ready to read.
How can I be notified if there was any change in the file with `select`?

Comment: Why do you have to use `select`. You could just read in the entire file and analyse it for changes. procfs files aren't that big. So it shouldn't even take too much off your performance

Answer (score 4):

`select(2)` does not report on "changes", instead "ready to read". From the [OpenGroup `select()` manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html):

> File descriptors associated with regular files always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions.

Kernel-provided files are a little strange -- they're not quite "regular files" -- but `select(2)` is not the tool to determine *changes* in these files.

If you want to spot changes, then you must use `inotify(7)`. Though I really wouldn't be surprised if not all files in `procfs(5)` use this mechanism -- many might not *know* when their underlying data changes. Consider `/proc/loadavg` -- it might change every single time you read it, but there's no real point making those changes visible via `inotify(7)`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't mean a call won't block.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know if there is any change in a file descriptor, you could use the library `libevent`.

> > libevent is an asynchronous event notification software library. The libevent API provides a mechanism to execute a callback function when
> >     a specific event occurs on a file descriptor or after a timeout has
> >     been reached. Furthermore, libevent also supports callbacks due to
> >     signals or regular timeouts.
>
> Currently, libevent supports /dev/poll, kqueue(2), select(2), poll(2),
>   epoll(4) and Solaris's event ports

Or you could also use `epoll`.

> epoll is a scalable I/O event notification mechanism for Linux, first introduced in Linux 2.5.44 [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll). It is meant to replace the older POSIX select(2) and poll(2) system calls, to achieve better performance in more demanding applications, where the number of watched file descriptors is large (unlike the older system calls, which operate at O(n), epoll operates in O(1) [2]). epoll is similar to FreeBSD's kqueue, in that it operates on a configurable kernel object, exposed to user space as a file descriptor of its own.

[Example of using epoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll)

Comment: `epoll` is neat, but doesn't know about file _changes_, only whether a file is _ready to read_.