# inotify_add_watch to /proc folder

Tags: inotify

I am trying to put "`inotify_add_watch`" for process.
My intent of doing this is to get notification when the process is killed.

my notification code is,

```
wd = inotify_add_watch(ifd, "/proc",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
```

But it does not notify even if the process deleted and the directory is removed from the 
/proc folder.

Answer (score 5):

In many Linux distributions, */proc* is mounted as `procfs`.
 `Inotify` does report some but not all events in `sysfs` and `procfs`.

reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify#Limitations
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs
http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq (search `procfs`)
[Select function on procfs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527772/select-function-on-procfs-file) (search `procfs`)

Answer (score 3):

Inotify does not support Pseudo files like sysfs and procfs

The proc and sys file system is sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It does not contain ``real'' files but rather runtime system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc).

Inotify reports only events that a user-space program triggers
through the filesystem API.  As a result, it does not catch remote
events that occur on network filesystems.  (Applications must fall
back to polling the filesystem to catch such events.)  Furthermore,
various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts are not
monitorable with inotify.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html